# Hourly historical weather data for USA

Tags: meteorology

I tried Google BigQuery but it is at day level.

Is there any source for hourly historical weather data for USA?

Comment: What type of data do you want? Gridded or point? Observations or reanalysis? How far back? Details, details, details.

Comment: I wasn't done messing with it, so can't absolutely confirm everything, but believe MADIS offered hourly (and even higher resolution) US ob archives in an FTP format that was reasonable to work with (after working out netCDF format)... I believe https://madis-data.ncep.noaa.gov is a starting point to making an account, but pretty sure I was having good success in bulk downloading data... it did seem a challenge to find before. Never as straightforward as it seems (a couple decades ago I'd write scripts to scrape NCDC easy, but seem to remember they made it harder over the years to automate?)

Comment: @BarocliniCplusplus For a set of sites across USA (art museums usually), point, 5 years back,  it should help us determine if the weather was inclement for public to visit the museum at given hour (i dont know if that should be observational or reanalysis)

Comment: I removed the tag [tag:earth-history] since it is generally used for questions about the history of the planet over billions of years (although the tag description is horrible).

Answer (score 2):

NCDC is a great resource for this type of stuff. [This data set](https://www.ncei.noaa.gov/metadata/geoportal/rest/metadata/item/gov.noaa.ncdc%3AC00532/html) should have exactly what you're looking for with hourly METAR reports from ASOS stations around the country. There's a ton of other data sets there but this should be closest to what you want.

Answer (score 2):

The Iowa Environmental Mesonet is a great source for hourly data, with a bunch of options for data viewing as well as automation of downloading. https://mesonet.agron.iastate.edu/

Answer (score 1):

Try the RAWS site at Western Regional Climate Center, [here](https://raws.dri.edu/).  When you visit the WRCC site, you will notice that the site is still under construction. Nevertheless, move your cursor over the state you wish data for, select that state, and an interactive map for that state will be displayed showing the available RAWS data sites from which you may choose.  An inventory of available data is then displayed for the chosen site.  Keep in mind that some Remote Automatic Weather Stations may have limited records, while others are voluminous.

You may also wish to check this site at the University of Utah, [here](https://mesowest.utah.edu/). Simply select the state for which you wish to retrieve hourly data, select the site of interest, and review the available data. Note that several and various data series are available from which hourly data may be accessed.  A user account is required, though, to download data for a series longer than one day.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just wanting to look up specific days when needed, it may wind up being easiest to use Weather Underground's historic data... go to wunderground.com, enter your location, then choose history:

[image]

and then there is a basic graph of the day, and additional readout of hourly observations further down the page.  I usually find WU a solid option if looking up a day.  For larger datasets to run statistical analysis or algorithms on, you'd need something with more flexibility to download data.